# Send API key using Spring @RestTemplate is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am developing a REST API using Spring Boot. My application relies on a 3rd party REST API for building the results and sending it back to the consumer of my API. I am having trouble invoking the 3rd party API service from my REST API application. As I need to supply an API key, I am using the `RestTemplate`'s `exchange(...)` method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userId}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUser(@PathVariable String userId,
        @RequestHeader String apikey) {

    String url = RESTAPIProperties.getUsersUrl() + "/users/{userId}";

    // Set headers for the request
    Map<String,Object> headersMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            Stream.of(
                    new SimpleEntry<>("apikey", apikey),
                    new SimpleEntry<>("Accept", "application/json")
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((e) -> e.getKey(), (e) -> e.getValue())));
    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = buildHttpEntity(headersMap);

    log.info("API Key: {}, Call sign: {}", apikey, userId);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class, userId);
}

// Returns HttpEntity object with the specified headers set
private HttpEntity<String> buildHttpEntity(Map<String,Object> headerParams) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headerParams.forEach((k,v)->headers.set(k, v.toString()));
    return new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
}
```

When I invoke the API method using GET and supply the API key in the `apikey` header in Postman, the request times out after a few seconds. In the logs, the API key and user ID is printed, so I know something's up with the `restTemplate.exchange(...)` call to the 3rd party service. However, if I hit the third party service directly using the same API key in Postman, a response is received promptly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a non-issue; it was a proxy server setting that was missing. Once I figured that out, I added the following to Catalina script and everything worked just fine.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxySet=true \
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.company.com \
-Dhttps.proxyPort=2345 $JAVA_OPTS"
```